# so hard to convert....registry C# and powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

- I have a PowerShell script that editing on windows registry...
- now I am learning C# and tried to open script with C# but registry
  didn't change. I don't know why
- so I want to convert PowerShell to C# I wanna create a converter !
- some thing like notepad replace but better

this code

```
$StartIsBackConfig = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\StartIsBack"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $StartIsBackConfig -Name "AutoUpdates" -Value 0 -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $StartIsBackConfig -Name "ModernIconsColorized" -Value 1 -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $StartIsBackConfig -Name "AllProgramsFlyout" -Value 0 -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $StartIsBackConfig -Name "CombineWinX" -Value 1 -Force
```

to this code

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\StartIsBack", true);
key.SetValue("AutoUpdates", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.SetValue("ModernIconsColorized", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.SetValue("AllProgramsFlyout", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.SetValue("CombineWinX", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: Are you building in 32-bit or 64-bit, and which registry do you want to edit: 32 or 64 bit version? Have you tried disposing `key` with a `using`? Also the values should be `0` and `1`, not `"0"` and `"1"`

Comment: @Charlieface 64bit .... and i tried using system.management.automation ... but still i have a big powershell script i wanna convert all fast

Comment: So you are compiling in 64 bit also, or in Any CPU? Have you checked the `Wow6432Node` to see if it's being redirected to 32bit? Have you tried anything else I suggested?

Comment: Any CPU... this is an optimization program for windows 10.... do you know a program will help me convert all fast ?

Comment: Software recommendations are explicitly off-topic for [so], and in any case I suggest you understand what code does rather than blindly converting. As I said: have you tried any of the suggestions I mention? To force 64-bit you can either compile to 64-bit, or you can open it using `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64)`